# Is it possible to use the .astype function to pass value name to my column that has mixed datatype?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, histogram

```py
num_cols = ['Complaint Type', 'City']

for i in range(0,len(num_cols),2): 
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
    plt.subplot(121)
    sns.distplot(citynan_df[num_cols[i]], hist=True, kde=False) 
    plt.subplot(122)
    sns.distplot(citynan_df[num_cols[i+1]], hist=True, kde=False) 
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have 2 column head Complaint Type and City and the idea is to plot city records against the complaint type in each column records

Comment: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Noise - Street/Sidewalk'
" Here data type is both object but i get that its calling for a float instead